# Ubuntu Studio 20.04, nvidia card not working with new drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam, ubuntu-studio

I am running Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3 LTS and run a few games on Steam. Recently I have found that my games have all switched to lowest res, if they work at all.

I am running an Nvidia Geforce 1650 and have freshly installed the latest drivers, which is 470 at the time of writing.

Output of `lshw -C display` :

```
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:179 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:178 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I am very new to Linux, but it looks like it is recognizing the hardware and it also recognizes the nouveau driver.

I have set the Software Updater to use the proprietary driver.

[image: Screenshot of Software Updater]

And I have set the NVIDIA X Server Settings to Performance Mode. Screenshot below:

[Screenshot of NVIDIA X Server Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7tOJ.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7tOJ.png)

Still when I try to play games, they do not find the video card. Below is a screenshot of the settings menu of Divinity 2 (running on Proton). Intel 630 is the only option available for graphics.

[image: Divinity Settings with only intel shown in graphics options]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: Switched from Ubuntu Studio to Ubuntu. Fresh install fixed the graphics problem (as well as my overheating problem, no sleep mode problem and a whole host of other issues).